# Node function return data type using big.js

Tags: node.js, big.js

I am new to node and trying to create a class that has three properties of which one is calculated.

```
const Big = require("big.js"); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-js

class Trade{
  constructor(name, buy, sell) {
    this.name = name;
    this.buy = Big(buy);
    this.sell = Big(sell);
  }
  profit() {
    return this.sell.minus(this.buy);
  }
};
```

This works in that I can create a new object using:

```
a = new Trade("Widget", 123.12345678, 321.87654321)
a.buy.toFixed(8)  // 123.12345678
a.sell.toFixed(8) // 321.87654321
```

However I cannot do:

```
a.profit.toFixed(8)

Uncaught TypeError: a.profit.toFixed is not a function
```

How can I create a calculated property in my class and have it return a "Big.js" data type so I may use the methods contained in the "Big.js" library such as "toFixed" ?

Comment: With a getter, one of the ways any property is created. Or just use a "this.xxx" and set it in the ctor, but that won't work if you update one of the underlying values (which could be fixed using setters).

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you are not calling the function which will return function definition. If you will be returning the number, `toFixed` will work and convert the number to string.

```
a.profit().toFixed(8) // invoke the function
```

Comment: So this way I would need to know the types of the the class attributes. Is there no way to have the class return a calculated attribute as a Big.js object?